# Is the Dragon Ball Super anime mostly filler?

Tags: anime-production, dragon-ball-super

I know the title might wound weird but were the first two arcs BOG and resurrection F and the episodes between the Champa tournament and Goku black arc filler untill the manga gave enough info to start the main arcs? Sorry if it doesn't make sense.

EDIT:I know that the battle of gods arc was in the manga but the resurrection F arc was just summarized and in the anime Ginyu was somehow added into the story.

Answer (score 1):

No, those arcs were also in the manga. Both the manga and the anime are based in Akira Toriyama main ideas and guidelines, though both the anime and manga have more room for the writers to put their own ideas because there isnt a manga fully made by Akira Toriyama like there was in Dragon Ball Z.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PbWLOvBIWlA

Comment: This is why I avoid using 'filler' to describe episodes of Super since the term doesn't really apply in this context. For lack of a better terminology, I prefer calling the fillerish episodes of Super "slice-of-life-episodes".